# After installing and configuring MUNIN (This webpage is not available)

Tags: apache, centos, munin

I tried installing munin and munin-node on CEntOS 6.5

via: `yum --enablerepo=epel install munin munin-node`

and finished everything in good installation. I have Configured Apache by (`vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf`) Editing Munin Apache configuration file and add following content:

```
Alias /munin /var/www/html/munin
<Directory /var/www/html/munin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also have created the user admin and Restart Services

```
/etc/init.d/munin-node start
chkconfig munin-node on
service httpd restart
```

I followed this installation guide [in this site](http://tecadmin.net/installing-munin-in-centos-rhel-and-fedora/#).
I have tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88678/error-404-munin-page-not-found) and [this too](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=munin).

But i cant access the web gui of MUNIN. any suggestion?